# Bash - Comparing a string to an array that contains wildcards?

Tags: bash

I have an array of possible file extensions, which contains some wild cards e.g.:

FILETYPES=("DBG" "MSG" "OUT" "output*.txt")

I also have a list of files, which I am grabbing the file extension from. I then need to compare the extension with the array of file extensions.

I have tried:

```
if [[ ${EXTENSION} =~ "${FILETYPES[*]}" ]]; then
  echo "file found"
fi

if [[ ${EXTENSION} == "${FILETYPES[*]}" ]]; then
  echo "file found"
fi
```

and

```
if [[ ${EXTENSION} =~ "${FILETYPES[*]}" ]]; then
  echo "file found"
fi
```

But to no avail

I tried:

```
if [[ "${FILETYPES[*]}" =~ ${EXTENSION} ]]; then
  echo "file found"
fi
```

However, it ended up comparing "txt" to "output*.txt" and concluding it was a match.

Comment: See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `FILETYPES=("DBG" "MSG" "OUT" "output*.txt")` First of all, avoid ALL_CAPS variable names except if these are meant as global environment variables.
- `"output*.txt"`: is ok as a globing pattern, for bash test `[[ $variable == output*.txt ]]` for example. But for Regex matching it needs a different syntax like `[[ $variable =~ output.*\.txt ]]`
- `"${FILETYPES[*]}"`: Expanding this array into a single_string was mostly a good approach, but it needs clever use of the `IFS` environment variable to help it expands into a Regex. Something like `IFS='|' regex_fragment="(${array[*]})"`, so that each array entry will be expanded, separated by a pipe `|` and enclosed in parenthesis as `(entry1|entry2|...)`.

Here is an implementation you could use:

`textscript.sh`

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

extensions_regexes=("DBG" "MSG" "OUT" "output.*\.txt")

# Expands the extensions regexes into a proper regex string
IFS='|' regex=".*\.(${extensions_regexes[*]})"

# Prints the regex for debug purposes
printf %s\\n "$regex"

# Iterate all filenames passed as argument to the script
for filename; do

  # Compare the filename with the regex
  if [[ $filename =~ $regex ]]; then
    printf 'file found: %s \n' "$filename"
  fi

done
```

Sample usage:

```
$ touch foobar.MSG foobar.output.txt
$ bash testscript.sh *
.*\.(DBG|MSG|OUT|output.*\.txt)
file found: foobar.MSG 
file found: foobar.output.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly compare a string with an array. Would you please try something like:

```
filetypes=("DBG" "MSG" "OUT" "output*.txt")
extension="MSG"                         # example
match=0
for type in "${filetypes[@]}"; do
    if [[ $extension = $type ]]; then
        match=1
        break
    fi
done
echo "$match"
```

You can save looping with `regex`:

```
pat="^(DBG|MSG|OUT|output.*\.txt)$"
extension="output_foo.txt"              # example
match=0
if [[ $extension =~ $pat ]]; then
    match=1
fi
echo "$match"
```

Please note the expressions of `regex` differ from wildcards for globbing.
As a side note, we conventionally do not use uppercases for user variables to avoid conflicts with system variables.